# Fetch data from API in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to know how I can get data from an API, create all react elements and only when it's all finished make the render on the app. Actually I use the hooks to do it but the problem is that in first start the app is rendered without API data, before, because I use hooks in the code to store and use API data, the app re-renders quickly with all data. (I learned that happens because when I change hooks value with the function the code continue and at the and restart without previous inputs)

I hope I was clear, my English is not too good

Comment: can you share your code, please, otherwise it will be difficult to help you

Answer (score 0):

This should make the work:

```
import React, {Button} from 'react';

const RequestTest = () => {
    const request = fetch('https://examples.com/data.json', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            firstParam: 'yourValue'
        })
    });

    return (
        <Button onClick={request}>
            Make simple request
        </Button>
    );
}
```

Comment: No I need to store and use in a loop the result of the request

Comment: Can you put it better in your code? That way I can write an better example to fits to your case

Comment: What you mean??

Answer (score 0):

The hook useEffect is called only after the component has been rendered so it is why data is empty at the beggining.

Comment: What is the way to do that correctly?

Comment: It is a normal behavior for react and you use it properly with useEffect. You could use ActivityIndicator when data is loading if you want

Comment: Ok but how I can known when the data in first start or the new data (inserted in the hook when user swipe or change watchingDay) are successful loaded?

I wish that the code first get all data, store it in the hooks and subsequently render all items